# Ansible linux deployment error {"failed": true, "parsed": false}

Tags: linux, bash, deployment, ssh, ansible

I have 3 linux machines, one for deployment and two to deploy the application on. I use Ansible for this and I have a problem.
At some point in my deployment process, I want to remotely execute a bash script that is on those 2 machines.

I have a playbook, app_stop.yml that looks like this:

```
### rel/app_stop.yml
#
# Erlang app stop playbook

-
  hosts: fe
  gather_facts: false
  sudo: app

  roles:
    - app_stop
```

My app_stop role has a task at some point when it invokes something to from the machine to ping the app, who will respond with pong. To simplify things I created a bash script that will echo pong, and I try to run that. It gives me the same error.

This is the app_stop role:

```
- name: Is the Erlang app installed?
  stat: path="{{ app_install_dir }}/{{ app_name_short }}/bin/{{ app_name_short }}"
  register: bin



- name: Ping the Erlang app
  command: "sudo /home/deploy/script.bash"
  when: bin.stat.exists == true
  register: ping
  ignore_errors: yes



- name: Stop the Erlang app
  command: "sudo -u {{ app_user }} {{ app_install_dir }}/{{ app_name_short }}/bin/{{ app_name_short }} stop"
  when: ping is defined and ping.stdout.find("pong") != -1
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: Determine the ERTS bin folder path
  shell: "ls {{ app_install_dir }}/{{ app_name_short }}/erts-*/bin/epmd"
  when: bin.stat.exists == true
  register: epmd
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: Stop the Erlang port mapping daemon (epmd)
  command: "sudo -u {{ app_user }} {{ epmd.stdout_lines[0] }} -kill"
  ignore_errors: yes
  when: epmd.stdout_lines is defined
```

The second task is important. The reason I have `ignore_errors: yes` is that if the app is closed I will stop the daemon , if not I will first stop the app, then the daemon.

Ping the Erlang app fails, even if I'm not doing any Erlang process stuff, I only invoke a shell script that prints pong. (and it works if I manually connect with ssh).

The error I get with Ansible is the next one:

```
failed: [stefan1] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
/bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
[sudo] password for deploy: 
{"changed": true, "end": "2015-12-24 03:04:55.207125", "stdout": "", "cmd": ["sudo", "/home/deploy/script.bash"], "start": "2015-12-24 02:59:55.095913", "delta": "0:05:00.111212", "stderr": "", "rc": 1, "warnings": []}
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/stefan-work-tiefighter-dev/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/stefan-work-tiefighter-dev/.ssh/config line 8: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 100975
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 0
Shared connection to 192.168.0.201 closed.
```

Comment: I'm guessing the `setlocale` error is breaking things.  Can you get rid of that?  I would also have ansible do the `sudo` like http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html describes.

Answer (score 0):

As chicks pointed out, you can use Ansible's "sudo" and "sudo_user" attributes on the Command tasks, it will be much cleaner.

Your second task from the "app_stop" role would look like this:

```
- name: Ping the Erlang app
  command: "/home/deploy/script.bash"
  when: bin.stat.exists
  register: ping
  ignore_errors: yes
  sudo: yes
```

Regarding the error message you're getting, that's from the OS complaining about not having the Locale correctly set up.
I've encountered the same problem before, and I usually use one Ansible task to ensure the Locale is configured properly, based on a Template file.

From your output, I'm guessing you're using CentOS, so here is the code I use.

It's interesting to define a variable for the locale, simply to improve reusability.

This would be the Template (*i18n.j2*):

```
LANG="{{ locale }}"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
LC_CTYPE="{{ locale }}"
```

And this would be the task to configure CentOS to use that:

```
- name: Ensure language and locale are correct
  template: src="i18n.j2" dest="/etc/sysconfig/i18n"
  sudo: yes
```